# Swagger 2.0 parameter that can be None or string type?

Tags: flask, swagger, swagger-2.0

I am defining a Swagger 2.0 YAML file for a route and the route has optional string parameters. The parameter can be either a string or empty.

When the route receives an empty string I get a schema validation error which says: None is not type 'string'.

How do I make the parameter accept None? Below the definition giving the issue.

```yaml
  parameters:
  - in: body
    name: jsonPost
    schema:
      type: object
      properties:
        optionalEmail:
          type: string
```

Comment: Your definition is correct and means `optionalEmail` is optional and can also be an empty string (`""`). The issue is server-side. Which server framework / validation library do you use?

Comment: Using Flask/python3, the call first passes through a 'router' directing calls to my server and the validation error comes from that router saying: validation error: None is not of type 'string'. Will look at the server-side more.

Comment: Can you use a default value with empty string as your default parameter?

Comment: I need it to be able to accept None because the caller of the endpoint does that and that call cannot be changed currently. I know in openapi version 3.0.0 you can specify that a input can be nullable, by doing nullable: true, wondering if there is an equivalent with swagger 2.0